# Looking for React Multiselect component with input number

Tags: javascript, reactjs, multi-select

Do you know if there is some react component which would allow to define input type number with multiselect functionality.
User put for example number `5` click enter it is added to selected list, then `8` etc.

Comment: react select has a multiselect option if that's what you're looking for: https://react-select.com/home.

Comment: I'm using Creatable Multiselect Example but I wonder if there is similar component which would limit creatable options to be numbers only

Answer (score 1):

if somebody needs, I ended up using React-select and checking value if it is not NaN.

```
const handleInputChange = (inputValue) => {
    if (!isNaN(inputValue)) {
      setInputValue(inputValue);
    }
  };
```